# Blocking Default Send button functionality and performing only custom action in outlook

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin

Objective: IN ADD-IN, i need to block calendar notification from being sent to attendees but at the same time i want to perform some custom action when send button is clicked.. In short i need to perform only custom action associated with send button and NOT the default function of SEND button.

i am using VSTO2010,MS Office 2007, .net 4.

I need to this on Ms office 2003,2007,2010 (support for 2007 and 2010 will be enough).

Answer (score 2):

You need to intercept the `OnClick` event of the Send button on the `CommandBar`.  Yes, even though Outlook 2010 uses the ribbon and doesn't show any command bar, there is still a programmatic `CommandBar` that contains buttons.  For compatibility, the ribbon buttons still cause the corresponding `CommandBarButton` object to raise events.

And to add to the complexity, the button you want doesn't exist until AFTER the "appointment" is turned into "meeting".

You'll need some fields:

```
private CommandBars mCommandBars;
private CommandBarButton mCommandButtonSendMeeting;
```

In your `NewInspector` event, add these lines

```
mCommandBars = this.Inspector.CommandBars;
mCommandBars.OnUpdate += CommandBars_OnUpdate;
```

elsewhere

```
private void CommandBars_OnUpdate()
{
    if (mCommandButtonSendMeeting == null)
    {
        mCommandButtonSendMeeting = (CommandBarButton)CommandBars.FindControl(Missing.Value, 2617, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        mCommandButtonSendMeeting.Click += CommandButtonSendMeeting_Click;
    }
}

private void CommandButtonSendMeeting_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    CancelDefault = true;
    // Do whatever here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a different solution. You really do not have to touch the buttons, there's nothing to do with the buttons. You have to use the events that Outlook provides for these purposes. Just include this line in your Add-in_StartUp:

```
Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
```

And of course, the implementation of the event handler:

```
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yihha!!");
    Cancel = true;
}
```

This will intercept any message you send. Works on Outlook 2010.